# HTTP server on board Turtlebot?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This should technically easy to do. Have people set up an HTTP server onboard a ROS robot, e.g. turtlebot3?

I want to allow remote control from a web app or mobile app of my robot, without requiring the client to be a ROS program. I want to use standard HTTP/HTML against the wireless connection, with the robot having a static IP address.

I think I need to locate the right python library that will do a simple web server and install and run it on the onboard Pi. In my googling I thought I saw that there was a problem with the interaction between threading of ROS and of an http server so something more elaborate was needed. Does anyone have a worked example?

Any thoughts or pointers?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267764/http-server-on-board-turtlebot?/) by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 628 on 2017-07-31

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-07-31**:
`python -m SimpleHTTPServer` with `rosbridge_suite`?

**Comment by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on 2017-07-31**:
In my googling I thought I saw that there was a problem with the interaction between threading of ROS and of an http server so something more elaborate was needed. Does anyone have a worked example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you taken a look at [`rosbridge_suite`](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbridge_suite) from [ROS Web Tools](http://robotwebtools.org/)? From the wiki:

> Rosbridge provides a JSON API to ROS
> functionality for non-ROS programs.
> There are a variety of front ends that
> interface with rosbridge, including a
> WebSocket server for web browsers to
> interact with. Rosbridge_suite is a
> meta-package containing rosbridge,
> various front end packages for
> rosbridge like a WebSocket package,
> and helper packages.

There's also [ROStful](https://github.com/benkehoe/rostful). From the README:

> ROStful is a lightweight web server
> for making ROS services, topics, and
> actions available as RESTful web
> services. It also provides a client
> proxy to expose a web service locally
> over ROS.

These aren't HTTP servers and I'm not too familiar with either of these, but they may be close to what you're looking for.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-07-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on 2017-07-31**:
Good pointers. I followed them and found: https://github.com/asmodehn/rostful which is a fork and actually has a developer who is using it, so we will be trying that one! Thanks!